# Google BreakPad macos, nothing happen

Tags: macos, google-breakpad

I have built BreakPad on Xcode 6 on Yosemite, no problems.
I have followed the Mac OS X implementation example.

When the application starts, the BreakPad looks good.
But when it crash, nothing happens except the normal crash reporter.

So I tested the BreakPadTest, but nothings happen too.

What can I do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the cause, it may help some people : 
Take care to verify that the path of generated minidump files exist, otherwise Breakpad will just freeze.